# Summarise pupil info together / present in a manageable meaning manner in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query, google-query-language

We use a school management system to track pupil attainment over a year. This comes out of the system in a raw format like this... https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LyMgxUJZ_D9TfR-aHM5HdFjPCf9goqvfEYud0ywIp54/edit?usp=sharing

I am really struggling with the best way to present this information. I have been looking at Google Data Studio and Google Sheets trying to reduce the number of empty cells to make it useful. I am hopeful that someone with a bit more expertise can pull this info together into something simplified that I could use for Data Studio.

Just for context we track pupils twice a year and thats what the tracking periods are. At one point a WG (working grade) is entered and then later in the year another one is entered.

- We need the pupil name, User ID, stage and reg class
- We only need the Teacher, Tracking Period and WG fields (all the rest can be removed)
- We also need the name of the subject so we know what subject the WG is for.

I'm really open to ideas on how to configure/query this into a different format so any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

hard to tell... add new sheet:

[image]

---

paste in A1:

```
=TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE('School Tracker'!A1:GK), 
 "where Col2 matches 
 'User ID|Forename|Surname|Stage|Reg\. Class|Teacher|Tracking Period|WG'", 0))
```

[image: 0]

---

or more compact:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE({TRIM(
 QUERY(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE('School Tracker'!A1:GK), 
 "where Col2 matches 
 'User ID|Forename|Surname|Stage|Reg\. Class|Teacher|Tracking Period|WG'", 0)), 
 "offset 2", 0),,999^99)); TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE('School Tracker'!A1:GK), 
 "where Col2 matches 
 'User ID|Forename|Surname|Stage|Reg\. Class|Teacher|Tracking Period|WG'", 0))}), 
 "where Col1 is not null", 0)), 
 "offset 1", 0))
```

[image: 0]